# multiprocessing of video frames in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am new to multiprocessing in python. I want to extract features from each frame of hour long video files. Processing each frame takes on the order of 30 ms. I thought multiprocessing was a good idea because each frame is processed independentle of all other frames.

I want to store the results of the feature extraction in a custom class.

I read a few examples and ended up using multiprocessing and Queues as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194884/assigning-return-value-of-function-to-a-variable-with-multiprocessing-and-a-pr). The result was disappointing though, now each frames takes about 1000 ms to process. I am guessing I produced a ton of overhead.

is there a more efficient way to process the frames in parallel and collect the results?

to illustrate, I put together a dummy example.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import numpy as np
import cv2

def main():
    #path='path\to\some\video.avi'
    coordinates=np.random.random((1000,2))
    #video = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
    listOf_FuncAndArgLists=[]

    for i in range(50):
        #video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,i)
        #img_frame_original = video.read()[1]
        #img_frame_original=cv2.cvtColor(img_frame_original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img_frame_dummy=np.random.random((300,300)) #using dummy image for this example
        frame_coordinates=coordinates[i,:]
        listOf_FuncAndArgLists.append([parallel_function,frame_coordinates,i,img_frame_dummy])

    queues=[Queue() for fff in listOf_FuncAndArgLists] #create a queue object for each function
    jobs = [Process(target=storeOutputFFF,args=[funcArgs[0],funcArgs[1:],queues[iii]]) for iii,funcArgs in enumerate(listOf_FuncAndArgLists)]
    for job in jobs: job.start() # Launch them all
    for job in jobs: job.join() # Wait for them all to finish
    # And now, collect all the outputs:
    return([queue.get() for queue in queues])         

def storeOutputFFF(fff,theArgs,que): #add a argument to function for assigning a queue
    print 'MULTIPROCESSING: Launching %s in parallel '%fff.func_name
    que.put(fff(*theArgs)) #we're putting return value into queue

def parallel_function(frame_coordinates,i,img_frame_original):
    #do some image processing that takes about 20-30 ms
    dummyResult=np.argmax(img_frame_original)
    return(resultClass(dummyResult,i))

class resultClass(object):
    def __init__(self,maxIntensity,i):
        self.maxIntensity=maxIntensity
        self.i=i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    a=main()
    [x.maxIntensity for x in a]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel processing in (regular) python is a bit of a pain: in other languages we'd just use threads but the GIL makes that problematic, and using multiprocessing has a big overhead in moving data around. I've found that fine-grained parallelism is (relatively) hard to do, whilst processing 'chunks' of work that take 10's of seconds (or more) to process in a single process can be much more straight-forward.

An easier path to parallel processing your problem - if you're on a UNIXy system - would be to make a python program which processes a segment of video specified on the command-line (i.e. a frame number to start with, and a number of frames to process), and then use the [GNU parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel) tool to process multiple segments at once. A second python program can consolidate the results from a collection of files, or reading from stdin, piped from `parallel`. This way means that the processing code doesn't need to do it's own parallelism, but it does require the input file to be multiply accessed and to extract frames starting from mid-points. (This might also be extendable to work across multiple machines without changing the python...)

Using `multiprocessing.Pool.map` could be used in a similar way if you need a pure-python solution: map over a list of tuples (say, `(file, startframe, endframe)`) and then open the file in the function and process that segment.

Comment: I am on a Windows system. I would like to give chunck-processing a try but I got stuck managing access to the video file from multiple processes. Just simply letting each process attempt to read frames via openCV made python hang.

Comment: I suggest testing things incremementally. Make a script that will process a segment of the video and check that it works (without using multiprocessing anywhere). Then try running that twice at the same time (even if they're processing the same part of the file) to check that there's no problems with multiple processes reading from the input file. Unless something is locking the file or otherwise preventing read-access to it, that should be fine but worth checking in isolation. Then, finally, extend the script to use multiprocessing. This should help isolate where and why it's hanging!

Comment: I just found out that I CAN read from the same video file simultaneously from many processes. what appears to be the problem is that passing too large of a variable into the queue freezes my python. I wonder if there is a parameter to change for queue size? Or an alternative approach to return values?

Comment: it looks like the solution to that freezing is to omit the join command above in the main function as pointed out under 'Joining processes that use queues' in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines

Comment: Good spot! I try and stay away from using the lower-level things in multiprocessing and instead try to use `multiprocessing.Pool.map` or `...map_async` methods. When I have had to use `Process` and `Queue` directly, I've made my own `Pool`-like class and dealt with cleanup by sending a specific 'terminate' command to the worker processes which then makes them exit. Then the `Process.join()` is effectively the last thing done during cleanup, knowing that they will have exited (or very soon will be).

Answer (score 1):

Multiprocessing creates some overhead for starting several processes and bringing them all back together.

Your code does that for *every* frame.

Try splitting your video into N evenly-sized pieces and processing *them* in parallel.

Put N equal to number of cores on your machine or something like that (your mileage may vary, but it's a good number to start experimenting with). There's no point in creating 50 processes if, say, 4 of them are getting executed and rest are simply waiting for their turn.

Comment: my problem with that suggestion is that it would require reading the frames within each process and that crashes my python. I think this has been described before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015792/how-to-get-frames-from-video-in-parallel-using-cv2-multiprocessing-in-python?rq=1

Comment: What about reading as many frames as your RAM allows in main process, then splitting those frames into N chunks and processing them in parallel, rinse, repeat?